# What is the philosophy of brahmakumaris?

Tags: philosophy, sects, brahmakumaris

I saw a certain new group active now a days in my home town. The organisation is called Brahmakumaris. Do they follow any scripture? What is their philosophy?

Does it come under the Vedic umbrella?

Comment: I am interested in this question too

Answer (score 2):

A wealthy merchant from Sindh, Pakistan started this movement. Brahma Kumaris call him Prajapita Brahma Baba.

In this animation [movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xXqT8TH-fM8) from Brahma Kumaris, they have explained their worldview. They believe in the four Yugas. Each Yuga consists of 1250 human years. Now we are at the very end of the Kaliyuga. At the end of Kaliyuga, Satyuga will begin. Brahma Kumaris think that by meditation, Satvik living, celibacy and austerity, the mass population will bring the Satyuga.
According to their belief, in Satyuga, human beings did not identify themselves with their body. They knew that they are eternal souls. The world was a very happy and prosperous place. The babies were created just by mere thought ("Sankalpa"). Gradually the power of souls diminished due to repeated birth. In Dwapara, the souls identified them with their bodies. So they felt attraction towards each other's bodies. From then, physical conjugation was needed to create new lives.

They believe in one God. They call their God Shiva Baba. He is formless, and he is light. In Dwapara Yuga, when people started identifying themselves with Bodies, they start erecting Shiva Lingas. At that time, they can't think anything beyond the body. So they added body to God also (in the form of Linga).
However, their God does not incarnate. It does not subject itself to birth and death. So it speaks to its children through some agents, such as Brahma Baba. Brahmakumaris consider Shankaracharya, Buddha, Jesus, Nanak as wiser souls who came to this world to spread the eternal message.